# How can I change the line distances without affecting the footnote distances?

Tags: footnotes, line-spacing

I know that by `\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{number}` it is possible to change the line distances, but it would also change the footnote distances.

How can I only change the line distances in the main text? I think there should be some changes in macros of `\@footnote` or some thing like this. Any idea?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

do not change the value of `\baselinestretch`. Use package `setspace` instead:

```
\documentclass{article}                 
\usepackage[english]{babel} 
\usepackage{setspace} 
\usepackage{blindtext} 
\setstretch{1.25}
\begin{document}            

\blindtext\footnote{\blindtext}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6):

For those using Memoir class: `\setstretch{1.25}` will give an error; no (big) problem!
Just add the line `\DisemulatePackage{setspace}` before `\usepackage{setspace}`:

```
\DisemulatePackage{setspace}
\usepackage{setspace}
\setstretch{1.25}
```

The above worked for me.
(Thanks to another contributor for this hint with Memoir class.)

Comment: The `memoir` class has a different command for setting the baseline stretch; for instance, 1.25 exactly corresponds to `\OnehalfSpacing`